# create specific json structure with php

Tags: php

i have rewritten the question, with a minimal example of code, and ommitted my erronneous effort. What i need to achieve, is the following. Having below code, i need to create a json that has a specific structure.

```
<?php
    $node = 5;
    $nid = 10;
    if ($node > 3):
        echo "status1";
        $date_from = date_create("2013-03-15");
        date_add($date_from, date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));
        echo date_format($date_from, "Y-m-d") . '-'; //here we print the from date element in the json
        if ($nid < 10)
        {
            $date_to = date_create("2019-09-25");
            date_add($date_to, date_interval_create_from_date_string("80 days"));
            echo date_format($date_to, "Y-m-d"); // here we print the to date element in the json
        }
        else
        {
            $date_to = date_create("2019-07-19");
            date_add($date_to, date_interval_create_from_date_string("30 days"));
            echo date_format($date_to, "Y-m-d"); // here we print the to date element in the json
        }
        echo "Valid until: ";
        $date_valid = date_create("2019-09-15");
        date_add($date_valid, date_interval_create_from_date_string("80 days"));
        echo date_format($date_valid, "Y-m-d");
    endif;
    $age = array(
        "charge1" => "2019-11-18",
        "charge2" => "2019-04-21",
        "charge3" => "2019-02-13"
    );
    
    foreach ($age as $key => $period):
        $date1 = date_create($period);
        $date2 = date_create("2017-11-8");
        $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
        if ($key + 1 == sizeof($age));
        if ($diff->invert) print '"* ';
        print intval($key + 1) . ' ';
        print date_create($period) . '-' . date_create("2020-01-15");
        date_add($period, date_interval_create_from_date_string("20 days"));
        echo 'Return_date: ' . date_format($period, "Y-m-d");
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

final resulted json (dates are just examples):

```json
[
    {status: 'status1', dates: { from: '01/09/2020', to: '01/09/2020'}, til: {label: 'Valid until:', date: 'Fri 04/09/2020'}},
    {status: '1', dates: { from: '01/09/2020', to: '04/09/2020'}, til: {label: 'Return_date:', date: 'Fri 01/09/2020'}},
    {status: '2', dates: { from: '04/09/2020', to: '28/09/2020'}, til: {label: 'Return_date:', date: 'Fri 04/09/2020'}}
]
```

Follows sample code of my approach:

```
<?php

$myArray = []; 

if(1 == 1) { # our if-statement
    $myArray["status"] = 'some data';
    $dates = []; # This array is the "dates" array
    $dates["from"] = "Date 1";
    if(1 == 2){ # our second if-statement
        $dates["to"] = "Date 2";
    }else {
        $dates["to"] = "Date 3";
    }
    $myArray["dates"] = $dates; 
    $myArray["til"] = [
        "label" => "valid until",
        "date" => "Date 4",
    ];
}

$json = json_encode($myArray, true); 
print_r($json);
```

Comment: You need to create that structure as an array, and then `echo json_encode($the_array_you_built)`

Comment: when you have a php object, you can just convert it to json. So you coul just have a class with the properties status, dates, til which are object themthelfs and then an array of this objekts. Then use json_encode (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: yes, i have used json_encode, please see i edited my question, i added my effort, but not exactly where i want to go. Could you please elaborate with a thorough answer example?

Comment: And what's the problem with the given code? What does not work yet? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Work in reverse from your desired output.  Json decode your expected json output to see that you need 3 indexed arrays on the first level.  These 3 subarrays contain associative elements with keys : `status`, `dates`, and `til`.  `dates` and `til` also contain associative elements. This is very basic programming -- please research more.

Answer (score 1):

Encode array to json with json_encode function

```
<?php

$yourArray = [];

foreach ($something as $key => $ofSomething) { // I assume ($age as $key => $period)
    // your logic to create node info
    $newArray = ['status' => '...', 'dates' => [....], ...];

    // push to parent array
    $yourArray[] = $newArray;
}

$json = json_encode($yourArray);

//echo or return, $json is string as json_encode returns string
echo $json;
```

Comment: yes, i have used json encode, my issue is how to create the array, so as to get the result - format i want

Comment: @rabasiw I updated my example for you, if you what specific structure, show me what exact json you want to get.

Comment: thank you, the desired json is in the question, where it says: final resulted json (dates are just examples):